# Using a combination of Firebase REST and Android SDK

Tags: android, rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Given an Android application where you register with email, password, and a unique username. The username is stored on the real time db.

I want to use the persistence feature of the real time db. But I don't want to use that feature for login or registration related things.

Since there is no method to selectively enable or disable persistence, my idea was to make my own HTTP requests to the server, where I don't want Firebase to handle any caching.

My question is, is this a good idea to do? Are there alternatives?